# X11 equivalents of grim, slurp, and wl-copy

Tags: x11, i3, wayland, screenshot, sway

I have been using Sway on Wayland for the last couple of years, but am currently stuck on X11/i3 due to various reasons...

The configs are compatible for the most part, but I am having trouble getting screenshots to work.

What is the easiest way I can replicate the functionality of `grim` and `slurp` in my i3 config?

This was my config line in Sway:

`bindsym $mod+Shift+s exec grim -g "$(slurp)" - | wl-copy`

Ideally I'd have something that works exactly the same...

Thank you!